# I want to delete some tags in a document using PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I mass delete tags like these in a document using PHP preg_replace?

```
<text:alphabetical-index-mark-start text:id="IMark169843024"/>
```

The only thing that is different from one to another is the number after IMark.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! - Now what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can fine-tune to whatever you need.  But in general terms you can do something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<text:.*?>~', '', $string);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF3iT4/2)

Or you can filter it all the way down with something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<text:alphabetical-index-mark-start text:id="IMark\d{9}"/>~', '', $string);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF3iT4/1)

Either way, it'll be pretty easy to strip these tags out.

Comment: Thank you :)
Meanwhile I found a similar regexp that works: 
    '/<text:alphabetical-index-mark(.*?)\/>/i'
What's the meaning of ~?

Comment: `.*?` means to match any character `.`, any number of times `*`, up until you hit the next part of the expression `?`.  In this case, we're designating the closing HTML tag as the next part of the expression.